# What's the term of "omission" in phonetics?

Tags: phonology, phonetics

What's the term of "omission" in phonetics?

Omission has a special term.Please help me.

Apheresis , hypheresis , and apocope are all kinds of omission or elision , but I want to know the name of this group.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but I've thought of two words. An **unsounded** letter is a letter that we don't pronounce. An **elision** is the the deliberate omission of a letter in writing or of a sound in speaking

Comment: [Silent letter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silent_letter)?

Answer (score 1):

*Elision* is the omission of a sound or syllable when speaking. *Elide* is the verb form.

Comment: Also [apocope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apocope)

Comment: An omission is the the deliberate omission of a letter in writing or of a sound in speaking.

Comment: It has a specific term.Elision is not right